# Getting URL String values with PHP for facebook opengraph

Tags: php

This might not be the most conventional way to share a facebook link, but I'm going to attempt it.

Lets say my site url is...

http://website.com/share.php?i=upload/image.jpg&u=username

and I'm looking to get the params of i and u

and I'm looking to put the i params inside of a facebook meta opengraph tag as so.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://website.com/upload/image.jpg" />
```

I tried doing this with javascript and facebook can't read the url so I'm going to try this with PHP. Can someone help me get the i param and pass it in the meta tag where the content attribute is.

Comment: Just use `$_GET['i']`? I feel I'm missing something trivial here.

Comment: I'll see if that works thanks I'm also using phonegap iOS facebook plugin, but for this example it's not really necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://website.com/<?php echo $_GET['i']; ?>" />
```

Comment: thanks that's exactly what I am trying to do.. I didn't realize you can just use $_Get to grab a string in PHP that is much easier than javascript.